# Pipe Filter using Inner Observable Predicate

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to get my head around RxJS. In particular I have a situation where I'm attempting to pipe emissions from an outer observable through a filter that has an inner observable predicate that depends on the output of the outer observable. By way of example:

```
outerObs.pipe(
    filter(x => myPredicate(x))
).subcribe()
```

where `mypredicate` is a function that returns `Observable<boolean>`. Obviously the above does not work as the `filter` operator expects a `boolean` and not `Observable<boolean>`. Is there a nice pipeable way to do this? I've tried looking at the `withLatestFrom` and `mergeMap` operators, but nothing really seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use one of the `*Map` operators: `mergeMap`, `exhaustMap`, `switchMap` or `concatMap`

Heres an example with `concatMap` that will guarantee initial order of emission:

```js
outerObs.pipe(
  concatMap(x => myPredicate(x).pipe(
    filter(subx => subx == true), // filter by sub value
    mapTo(x)                      // map sub value back to outer value
  ))
).subcribe()
```

See this **[mergeMap vs exhaustMap vs switchMap vs concatMap](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/mergeMap-vs-exhaustMap-vs-switchMap-vs-concatMap/)** comparison to pick the right one.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this is what I went for, albeit a mergeMap - the mental leap was piping the inner observable :)